# How to Speech recognize a Telephone number on UWP Windows 10?

Tags: c#, grammar, speech

i have this problem:

I Can to use a Speech recognize with a Grammar List to Recognize a specific Commands, But when I need to capture a Telephone Number or zipcode only can cath the first number..

I know that i Can use Dictation Grammar, but what happen whit your app if dont have internet? Right Crash!!!
Im finding a method with ListGrammar or  SRGSGrammar.XML where i Could recognize a lot of numbers in same method.

```
    private async void Capturar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        SpeechRecognizer reco = new SpeechRecognizer(language);
        string[] responses = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", };



        var listConstraint = new Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionListConstraint(responses, "Comandos");

        reco.Constraints.Add(listConstraint);

        await reco.CompileConstraintsAsync();
        IAsyncOperation<SpeechRecognitionResult> op = reco.RecognizeAsync();

        reco.Timeouts.EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.2);
                op.Completed += HandleCompilationCompleted;



    }

    public async void HandleCompilationCompleted(IAsyncOperation<SpeechRecognitionResult> asyncInfo, AsyncStatus status)
    {

        var result = asyncInfo.GetResults();
        string caso = result.Text;


        if (result.Confidence != SpeechRecognitionConfidence.Rejected)
        {

            {
                string recognizedText = result.Text;

                // var dialog2 = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(result.Text);

                // await dialog2.ShowAsync();
               resp = resp+ result.Text;
                reco.Timeouts.EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.2);
            };
            var dialog2 = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(resp);

            await dialog2.ShowAsync();
        }
        //  }
    }
```

Comment: This code is in uwp (universal Windows 10 App)

Comment: Yes but if you implement only can recognize only one number, is not like a dictation grammar, but i need a similar funtion but without use internet.. (Dictaction Grammar use search web)